# Maven Building Error

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, ycsb, maven-clean-plugin

When I try to run

```
mvn clean package
```

I am getting the following error

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven /plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Reactor Summary:
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] YCSB Root ......................................... FAILURE [21.334s]
 [INFO] Core YCSB ......................................... SKIPPED
 [INFO] Cassandra DB Binding .............................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] HBase DB Binding .................................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] Hypertable DB Binding ............................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] DynamoDB DB Binding ............................... SKIPPED
 [INFO] ElasticSearch Binding ............................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] Infinispan DB Binding ............................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] JDBC DB Binding ................................... SKIPPED
 [INFO] Mapkeeper DB Binding .............................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] Mongo DB Binding .................................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] OrientDB Binding .................................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] Redis DB Binding .................................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] Voldemort DB Binding .............................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] YCSB Release Distribution Builder ................. SKIPPED
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 21.581s
 [INFO] Finished at: Sun Jun 23 14:32:40 IST 2013
 [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/238M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
```

**pom.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/3.0.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/3.0.5 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.yahoo.ycsb</groupId>
  <artifactId>root</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.4</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>YCSB Root</name>

  <description>
    This is the top level project that builds, packages the core and all the DB bindings for YCSB infrastructure.
  </description>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- voldemort -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>checkstyle</groupId>
      <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
      <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    Nail down slf4j version to 1.6 so that it defaults to no-op logger.
    http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <!-- Properties Management -->
  <properties>
    <maven.assembly.version>2.2.1</maven.assembly.version>
    <hbase.version>0.94.3</hbase.version>
    <cassandra.version>0.7.0</cassandra.version>
    <infinispan.version>7.1.0.CR1</infinispan.version>
    <openjpa.jdbc.version>2.1.1</openjpa.jdbc.version>
    <mapkeeper.version>1.0</mapkeeper.version>
    <mongodb.version>2.9.0</mongodb.version>
    <orientdb.version>1.0.1</orientdb.version>
    <redis.version>2.0.0</redis.version>
    <voldemort.version>0.81</voldemort.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <thrift.version>0.8.0</thrift.version>
    <hypertable.version>0.9.5.6</hypertable.version>
  </properties>


  <modules>
    <!--module>build-tools</module-->
    <module>cassandra</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>hbase</module>
    <module>hypertable</module>
    <module>dynamodb</module>
    <module>elasticsearch</module>
    <!--<module>gemfire</module>-->
    <module>infinispan</module>
    <module>jdbc</module>
    <module>mapkeeper</module>
    <module>mongodb</module>
    <module>orientdb</module>
    <!--module>nosqldb</module-->
    <module>redis</module>
    <module>voldemort</module>
    <module>distribution</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
          <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>checkstyle</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Through **wget http://repo.maven.apache.org** it's not showing any error. Can any one help me in this?

I am trying to run YCSB benchmark, I got this error.

Comment: it is showing error at end.

 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact.

download a new copy of maven and configure it in environment variable and try again. also update your post with pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you are not able to connect to the maven repository at : http://repo.maven.apache.org

Try a different repository, [details here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories) or add to your pom, this:

```
<repository>              
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Central</name>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: pom.xml code has been added can you check it..Thanx for the immediate reply

Comment: @Rohit You may need to change your maven seetings.xml to configure te repositories. settings.xml is present under ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml . Follow this link to understand that file and to know how to configure repositories: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: Thanx i got it...proxy issue

Answer (score 1):

There can be 2 possibilities.

1. You have experinced connection problems to central repository.
2. Something is wrong in your pom.xml

The exception says that the problem is not in YCSB but in connection to repository while trying to download maven clean plugin.

So, send here pom.xml and just in case check you network connection and try again. Is there a chance that you access internet via browser using proxy while maven does it directly, so the connection is unavailable? Or firewall in your company checks user-agent and does not allow you to connect to repository?

EDIT:

BTW it seems that version 2.4.1 is not in the repository. At least manually I can see version 1.0, 1.0 beta and 1.5

Comment: pom.xml code has been added can you check it..Thanx for the immediate reply

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you are behind a proxy please add proxy settings in `~/.m2/settings.xml` and try.

Example:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>proxy host name</host>
        <port>port</port>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <nonProxyHosts>exclutions</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you're maven cannot connect to the repository defined to pull the required artifacts. Are you behind a proxy? In that case you would require to configure the proxy settings in maven - conf - settings.xml.